# RabbitMQ connection in blocking state?

Tags: java, rabbitmq

I connect to RabbitMQ server that time my connection display in blocking state and i not able to publish new message 
i have ram of 6 gb free and disk space also be about 8GB

how to configure disk space limit in RabbitMQ

Comment: Can you provide more information?  Code samples snapshots of the management gui in a browser perhaps.

Comment: Code wise, related fix and discussion:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14386392/how-to-detect-alarm-based-blocking-rabbitmq-producer/17104037#17104037

Answer (score 13):

I got the same problem. Seem like the rabbitmq server was using more memory than the threshold

http://www.rabbitmq.com/memory.html

I ran following command to unblock these connections:

rabbitmqctl set_vm_memory_high_watermark 0.6

(default value is 0.4)

Comment: The above command shall be run while rabbitmq is still running and it shall reflect immediately.

Answer (score 5):

By default, [disk_free_limit](source: [1]) must exceed 1.0 times of RAM available. This is true in your case so you may want to check what exactly is blocking the flow. To do that, read [rabbitmqctl man](source: [2]), and run the last_blocked_by command. That should tell you the cause for blocking.

Assuming it is memory (and you somehow didn't calculate your free disk space correctly), to change disk_free_limit, read [configuring rabbitmq.config](source: [1]), then open your rabbitmq.config file and add the following line: `{rabbit, [{disk_free_limit, {mem_relative, 0.1}}]}` inside the config declaration. My rabbitmq.config file looks as follows:

```
[
{rabbit, [{disk_free_limit, {mem_relative, 0.1}}]}
].
```

The specific number is up to you, of course.

Sources

1. http://www.rabbitmq.com/configure.html#configuration-file
2. http://www.rabbitmq.com/man/rabbitmqctl.1.man.html